# Using MPI_Scatter with C++ - Scattering over different communicators

Tags: c++, mpi

In C++, an example for using MPI_Scatter is:

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(sendbuf, 100, MPI::INT, recvarr, 100,MPI::INT, root);
```

This scatters the contents of `sendbuff` into 100 separate process to make `recvarr` on each process, ***but ONLY in the MPI World communicator***.

Unlike MPI_Scatter in C, the C++ version doesn't have an input for the communicator. How can I modify this example to work for any communicator, and not just MPI_COMM_WORLD?

For example, say my communicator is named `comm`. How can I scatter `sendbuff` within the `comm` communicator group instead of MPI_COMM_WORLD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`comm.Scatter(sendbuf, 100, MPI::INT, recvarr, 100,MPI::INT, root);`

The object to the left of the `.` is the MPI communicator argument. `MPI::COMM_WORLD` happens to be a pre-defined instance of an MPI communicator that corresponds to the C binding's pre-defined `MPI_COMM_WORLD`

Note that the MPI C++ bindings have been deleted in MPI-3.0, because they were underused, hard to maintain, and had clunky misunderstandings like this.